# Snap でインストールした neovim コマンドが zsh から見つからない

Tags: zsh, neovim

今日、昨日の深夜まで使っていたPCを起動してターミナルからNeoVimを呼び出そうとしたんですが、`zsh: command not found: nvim`とか言われて混乱しています。
マジで機能の深夜までバリバリに使っていました。

とりあえずwhichコマンドをたたいてみても同様に`not found`が返ってきます。
しょうがないのでsnap installを打つと`snap "nvim" is already installed`とか言われて怖いです。（最初に導入するときもsnapを使いました）

## 環境

- Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS (on wsl)
- zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-ubuntu-linux-gnu)

Comment: `locate nvim` と `echo $path` の実行結果はどうなりますか

Comment: `$ locate nvim`
zsh: command not found: locate
`$ echo $PATH`
nvimっぽいパスはない…これっぽいですね
しかしパスってどうやって調べるんです？

Comment: `find / -name "nvim"` とするとどうなりますか？

Comment: /home/USER/.local/share/nvim
/home/USER/.local/state/nvim
/home/USER/.config/nvim
/home/USER/snap/nvim
/home/USER/.cache/nvim
/snap/nvim
出てきました

Comment: 結果をファイルのみに絞り込むため、`find / -name "nvim" -type f` とした方がよいかも。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Snap でインストールしたパッケージのコマンド自体は `/snap/bin` を確認してみてください。

zsh の PATH に上記パスを追加するには、例えば以下のような方法があるようです。

[snapでインストールしたコマンドがzshでPATH通ってない](https://qiita.com/sameyasu/items/072882ee92bca54906d8)

> `/etc/zsh/zprofile` の末尾に以下を追記した。
>
> ```bash
> # Expand $PATH to include the directory where snappy applications go.
> snap_bin_path="/snap/bin"
> if [ -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}}" -a -n "${PATH##*${snap_bin_path}:*}" ]; > then
>     export PATH=$PATH:${snap_bin_path}
> fi
> ```